# Verifying Vector Addition?

Tags: formal-verification, loop-invariant

I'm trying to verify a vector add function in Whiley.  This is what I had so far:

```
function add(int[] v1, int[] v2) -> (int[] v3)
requires |v1| == |v2|
ensures |v3| == |v1|:
    //
    v3 = v1
    //
    for i in 0..|v3|:
        v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i]
    //
    return v3
```

However, verifying this on [whileylabs](https://whileylabs.com) produces an error saying "possible index out of bounds" on `v1[i]`.  I'm a bit confused as this seems OK to me!

Comment: I'm guessing, but what happens if |v1| < |v3| ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Whiley does not (at this time) automatically infer a loop invariant connecting the size of `v3` and `v1`.  Since `v3` is modified in the loop, information we know about it from before the loop is lost (i.e. that `|v1| == |v3|`).  This version verifies:

```
function add(int[] v1, int[] v2) -> (int[] v3)
requires |v1| == |v2|
ensures |v3| == |v1|:
    //
    v3 = v1
    //
    for i in 0..|v3| where |v1| == |v3|:
        v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i]
    //
    return v3
```